# R code - Dates returned NULL after applying date formatting

Tags: r, date, format

I am trying to extract the date as yyyy-mm-dd (2008-12-30) using R. So, only the year, month and day.

My original date in my data looks like this `"2008-12-30 00:00:00.0000000"`.

I have tried below:

```
dfs$date<-as.POSIXct(dfs$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

dfs$date <-as.Date(dfs$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

both two returned null for 10% of the original dates in my data, but the rest 90% seemed to be right.

I would really appreciate any suggestion to fix this!

Comment: Please check the 10% of the dates.  It must be different format.  For me `as.Date` works fine `str1 <- "2008-12-30 00:00:00.0000000."
> as.Date(str1, "%Y-%m-%d")#
[1] "2008-12-30"`

Comment: If you have known examples where it does not work, please make this question more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) by including those examples.

Comment: @akrun Thank you!! realized that have some "//NAs" in my data which was causing the converting date type problems

Answer (score 0):

If you original source data is just text, you might be able to use `substr` here:

```
x <- "2008-12-30 00:00:00.0000000."
substr(x, 1, 10)
[1] "2008-12-30"

# or
as.Date(substr(x, 1, 10))
```

If some of your data does have problems, the above suggestion might get around that problem, assuming every row does in fact start with a 10 character date string.